# How to query array of coordinate objects in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am storing OCR text detected on images using their coordinate data, where the 'bounds' field of type JSON:

```
id: 89
image_id: 36
text: ITALIAN
bounds: [{"x": 160, "y": 51}, {"x": 225, "y": 50}, {"x": 225, "y": 63}, {"x": 160, "y": 64}]
```

The 'bounds' represent the coordinates of the box surrounding the string so that I can identify the string location on the image.
How would I be able to query for words that are within a user defined bounding box? For example:

```
[{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 200, "y": 0}, {"x": 0, "y": 200}, {"x": 200, "y": 200}]
```

So far, what I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM bounding_boxes 
  where image_id = 36 
  and (JSON_EXTRACT(`bounds` , '$**.x') >= 0 or JSON_EXTRACT(`bounds` , '$**.x') <= 200)
  and (JSON_EXTRACT(`bounds` , '$**.y') >= 0 or JSON_EXTRACT(`boundss` , '$**.y') <= 200);
```

Comment: Use not JSON but GEOMETRY for `bounds` and according spatial function (for example, MBROverlaps()).

Comment: or use geojson instead of plain json. Otherwise you have to work out the math yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will change the field type accordingly.